# How to visualizate simple dependency graphs using php?

Tags: php, svg

Is there any libraries to visualizate simple dependency graphs?
I suppose that SVG is good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about PHP libraries, but there's the tool called [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) which can be invoked from your PHP code and produce .SVG visialization of your graph.

Comment: Yeah, I meant "dependency graph".
Thank you for great library.

Answer (score 2):

GraphViz does a nice job for tiny graphs, but not for huge ones. If your graph is reasonlably large, try [aiSee](http://www.aisee.com/) or have a look at the alternatives on [this list](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Math/Combinatorics/Software/Graph_Drawing/).

Answer (score 1):

I really like Google Chart API: http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/chart/

Really simple to implement and there are quite a lot of graph styles.

Comment: I tried it using the "org chart" example, but that only allows for one parent per node... any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout http://thejit.org/

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/ for drawing simple graphs.

Answer (score 0):

[ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/download.html) is the best, and it has a lot of flavors thus has versions for PHP/ASP/COM/VB/.NET/JSP/Java/ColdFusion/Perl/Python/Ruby/C++.

By learning one, you then be able to use in many programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

The if you mean graphs like in "dependency graph", then [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) should be mentioned.